# Ruby: Applying of method of self to each argument yielded

Tags: ruby, enumerable

Is there a better way in Ruby to call a method of self with each arguments yielded by an enumerable? Something that would reduce the following code:

```
class Cook
  def cook_dinner(*recipes)
    recipes.each { |recipe| cook recipe }
  end

  def cook(recipe)
    do_something_with recipe
  end
end
```

to something like this?

```
class Cook
  def cook_dinner(*recipes)
    recipes.apply_to_each(:cook)
  end

  def cook(recipe)
    do_something_with recipe
  end
end
```

Comment: `recipes.each(&:cook)` ?

Comment: The former version is better for readability, there's no real benefit in conciseness

Comment: @bjhaid it won't work, because recipe does not have `cook` method defined on it.

Comment: `recipes.each(&self.method(:cook))` should work

Comment: `recipes.each(&method(:cook))` or, just out of curiosity: I would make `cook` method `private` and use `recipes.each(&method(:send).curry[:cook])` :)

Comment: I would still use the current version. It is clearer and virtually just as short.